# CiviDiscount Not working with 4.7.1 upgrade

Tags: cividiscount

I recently upgraded to version 4.7.1  and when I click on Admin-> CiviDiscount  and it goes directly to the CiviCRM Home page.

Any help????

Comment: Hmm - this doesn't happen on the demo site at http://demo.civicrm.org.  That's not terribly helpful, but is a good first troubleshooting step.

Comment: Noticed that the demo site is using version 3.2 for CiviDiscount.   Not clear what this changed.  It does not show up as the current extension in the system status notices.

Comment: Update the extension also. It probably works but the URL in the menu is wrong.

Comment: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16465/cividiscount-navigation-url-incorrect?rq=1