# Can't administer cividiscount afer upgrade to 4.7.7

Tags: cividiscount

I've recently upgraded to 4.7.7 and it seems this has caused me to be unable to administer cividiscount. Current discounts are working, the extension is listed properly, there are/were no errors at any point. It's just when you go to the cividiscount URL you get the main civiCRM dashboard!

Previous version was 4.7.4, cividiscount version in 3.2 running on Drupal 7.43

I have noted a similar question [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9376/cividiscount-not-working-with-4-7-1-upgrade) same sounding problem on a different version, no solutions.

How do I even start finding out what this is? do I need to turn on some sort of debugging and look at lots of logs?

Comment: Not a comment but an echo - I'm encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue (Joomla 3.5/CiviCRM 4.7.8) after a tests on my local install, I found that activating the debug (Administer > System Settings > Debugging & Error Handling), browsing the CiviDiscount loaded. Turned off debug and loaded. Hope this may help.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem in Drupal until I realized that the menu link was wrong and when I put in the correct URL manually, it would indeed go to the CiviDiscount administration page.

The link that the menu takes me to:
https://dev.example.com/civicrm/cividiscount_reset_1

The correct link:
https://dev.example.com/civicrm/cividiscount?reset=1

Even though I don't know why this happened, it's worth checking out. To fix it, edit the link URL in the menu:
Administer > Custom Data & Screens > Navigation then right-click menu item and edit. If you are unable to edit it from here, you could create a new link.

Comment: Editing may not work. I had to post a similar question about it here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16465/cividiscount-navigation-url-incorrect