# CiviDiscount Navigation URL incorrect

Tags: drupal, upgrade, extension, cividiscount

After upgrading to 4.7.0 on Drupal 7.50, the link to the CiviDiscount administration in the CiviCRM navigation menu is incorrect (`cividiscount_reset_1`); see screenshot below.

[image]

I have attempted to edit the URL by going to Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Navigation Menu. When I open the link to edit it, it reports the wrong information entirely and notice that the info seems to be from the link above it; see screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

In keeping with the formatting of the other links, which start at `civicrm/`, I edited the link to include the proper URL to the CiviDiscount administration page. I tested this link independently (full URL) in a browser and made sure that it works: `/civicrm/cividiscount?reset=1`. When I save the edit, it shows the same "all reports" that it was before, in the screenshot above. I created a *new* link in the menu, but it goes to `http://civicrm/cividiscount?reset=1` which obviously doesn't work. When I put in the full URL, `https://dev.example.com/civicrm/cividiscount?reset=1`, the URL that it goes to is actually `cividiscount_reset_1`, the original incorrect link from the beginning.

Considerations:

- all other links in the menu look normal, without the underscores and work
- the correct URL for CiviDiscount works when entered manually
- CiviDiscount appears to be functioning normal
- I am running CiviDiscount version 2.6

Comment: I have done some investigating and realized that this version of CiviDiscount is not compatible with CiviCRM 4.7 version. I will upgrade it and see if that fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me Christia, but my permissions are fine, and I am running v 3.3 of cividiscount and it is not working in my wordpress site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was resolved once I upgraded the extension to 3.3 and corrected the permissions for the extensions folder for the group. `chmod -R 775 sites/default/files/civicrm/ext`. After the CiviCRM upgrade, the extensions directory changed so permissions needed to be reset also.

Comment: Make sure to mark this as the correct answer. :)