# CiviDiscount Navigation URL broken on Joomla

Tags: cividiscount

After upgrading to Joomla 3.6.5 (from, I forget which - should have made a note) the CiviDiscount navigation URL is broken (sends me to the CiviCRM dashboard). I also did a more minor update of CiviCRM to 4.7.14 (from 4.7.10ish) immediately after.

[This question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16465/cividiscount-navigation-url-incorrect) deals with a similar problem in Drupal. This is the URL that I am sent to from the menu:
http://[site]/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/cividiscount

What should it be instead?

Comment: What version of CiviDiscount did you install? Make sure you have the latest version 3.3.

Comment: Yes, it is 3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I discovered that the CiviVolunteer menu URLs were also broken, I updated to the most recent version of CiviVolunteer. That fixed the CiviVol broken URLs, and the CiviDiscount URL is also fixed.