# can't administer CiviDiscount (v3.3) after upgrade to civicrm 4.7.16 wordpress

Tags: wordpress, extension, cividiscount

I recently upgraded my civicrm wordpress installation and can no longer access the administration screen for cividiscount.  The navigation menu link (Administer > CiviDiscount) points to http://mydomain.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/cividiscount and that just lands me back on the CiviCRM dashboard. I've tried http://mydomain.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=cividiscount but that lands me on a white screen that just says "Thank you for creating with WordPress. Version 4.7.2"

discount code field still appears on event registration form.

Comment: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16465/cividiscount-navigation-url-incorrect?rq=1

Comment: I've confirmed that I am running v 3.3 and the permissions on my extensions folder and sub folder are set to 775, so the solution that worked for you Christia did not work for me.