# New navigation menu item broken url

Tags: wordpress, menu, urls

I basically have the same problem as in [CiviDiscount Navigation URL incorrect](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16465/cividiscount-navigation-url-incorrect) not for a special extensions though, but for the search. I'm using CiviCRM 5.44.0 on Wordpress 5.8.2. I added this url to a new navigation item: `civicrm/contact/search&force=1&qfKey=0&reset=1`

When using the menu item it navigates me to: `wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fsearch_force_1_qfKey_0_reset_1`

The important characters are just converted to underscores. Is this a saftey setting I have to disable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to do this: civicrm/contact/search?force=1&qfKey=0&reset=1